# How to make a CSV file for a webscraper?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a list of tuples that I need to put into a CSV file using pandas but not sure how. I was thinking of putting them in a dic but that didn't work. Here is the list I am trying to get into a CSV.

```
tables = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"pane"})[0].find_all("table")

    if (len(tables) > 4):
        product_list = [
            (
                t[0].findAll("div", {"class":"headline"})[0].text.strip(), #title
                t[0].findAll("div", {"class":"copy"})[0].text.strip(),     #description
                t[1].text.strip(),                                         #product number
                t[2].text.strip(),                                         #category number
                t[3].text.strip()                                          #price
            )
            for t in (t.find_all('td') for t in tables[4].find_all('tr'))
            if t
        ]
    elif (len(tables) == 1):
        product_list = [
            (
                t[0].findAll("div", {"class":"catNo"})[0].text.strip(),    #catNo
                t[0].findAll("div", {"class":"headline"})[0].text.strip(), #headline
                t[0].findAll("div", {"class":"price"})[0].text.strip(),    #price
                t[0].findAll("div", {"class":"copy"})[0].text.strip()      #description
            )
            for t in (t.find_all('td') for t in tables[0].find_all('tr'))
            if t
        ]
    else:
        print("could not parse main product\n\n")
        time.sleep(timeDelay)

    print(product_list)
    time.sleep(timeDelay)

    if len(tables) > 5:
        add_product_list = [
            (
                t[0].findAll("div", {"class":"title"})[0].text.strip(), #title
                t[0].findAll("div", {"class":"copy"})[0].text.strip(),  #description
                t[1].text.strip(),                                      #product number
                t[2].text.strip(),                                      #category number
                t[3].text.strip()                                       #price
            )
            for t in (t.find_all('td') for t in tables[5].find_all('tr'))
            if t
        ]
        print(add_product_list)
        time.sleep(timeDelay)
```

I have already imported pandas but don't know what to put in the data frame as they are not each named specific items they are all lumped together.Any help would be great as this is one of my fist more advanced scrapes I have made. Thanks!

Here is also the first part of the script with the HTML/URL I am scraping.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import random
import csv
import pandas as pd

f = pd.DataFrame

filename = "Qiagen_Scrape_final.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")
headers = "product_name, product discription, Cat No, product number, price\n"
f.write('headers')

product_urls =[
'https://www.qiagen.com/us/shop/pcr/primer-sets/miscript-precursor-assays/#orderinginformation', 
'https://www.qiagen.com/us/shop/pcr/primer-sets/miscript-primer-assay-plate/#orderinginformation',
]
```

Comment: can you share a sample of the html you are scraping?

Comment: here is the first part of the code with the html/ URLs I am using.

Comment: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import random
import csv
import pandas as pd

f = pd.DataFrame

filename = "Qiagen_Scrape_final.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")
headers = "product_name, product discription, Cat No, product number, price\n"
f.write('headers')

product_urls =[
'https://www.qiagen.com/us/shop/pcr/primer-sets/miscript-precursor-assays/#orderinginformation', 
'https://www.qiagen.com/us/shop/pcr/primer-sets/miscript-primer-assay-plate/#orderinginformation',

Comment: @briancaffey ...

Comment: one moment, I had a look at the content you are trying to scrape and I think I understand the problem you are facing. There is a complicated table structure. I would like to show you have you can create a simple dict into a pandas dataframe from a table.. one moment

Comment: I have added an answer, hopefully this can get you started on how you would scrape all of the data you need from this site.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can use a dictionary to populate a dataframe with this data:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 
import time 
import random 
import pandas as pd 

product_urls = [
  'https://www.qiagen.com/us/shop/pcr/primer-sets/miscript-primer-assay-plate/#orderinginformation'
]

html = requests.get(product_urls[0]).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

container = soup.find('table')
tables = container.find_all('tr')

dic_list = []
for t in tables[13:]:
    data = t.find_all('td')
    dic = {}
    try:
        dic['title'] = data[0].find('div').text
        dic['description'] = data[0].find("div", {"class":"copy"}).text,  
        dic['prod_number'] = data[1].text,                                        
        dic['cat_number'] = data[2].text,                                        
        dic['price'] = data[3]['price']  
    except:
        pass
    dic_list.append(dic)


df = pd.DataFrame(dic_list)
print(df.sample(3))


       cat_number    description price prod_number  \
25  (MS00064316,)   ((ZmU65-2),)  93.1   (218300,)   
13  (MS00064232,)   ((ZmU49-1),)  93.1   (218300,)   
26  (MS00064323,)  ((OssnoR28),)  93.1   (218300,)   

                                title  
25   Zm_U65-2_1 miScript Primer Assay  
13   Zm_U49-1_1 miScript Primer Assay  
26  Os_snoR28_1 miScript Primer Assay
```

Finally, save your `csv` file like this:

```
df.to_csv('sample_csv.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you that makes more sense now. My only question is this is for one URL with all the same tags but I need it to print out even if it has another tag in its place if that makes sense. That is why I have some many tuples because some of the urls use different tags for some of the fields or don't have a second table.

Comment: Yes, @user9269112 I think you had a good approach with the tuples, but it would be hard to show how to make a dictionary with so many different possible table structures. Obviously it is best if you know the structure of the html before you scrape a page. But the pattern I showed here should hold true. You could have lots of fields and products that don't have values for those fields contain `None` or `NaN` values.

Comment: Thank you again @briancaffey yeah this site was a bit more complicated to scrape then I first thought when looking at the HTML didn't think they would change their tags and page layouts for so many of their products and pages.